# Sharing an IndexedDB stores with with other users

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I am on a heavily restricted network where basically all I can do is file sharing. I would like to build an application where users can log and manage basic job information… However without administration access I cannot use standard database services.

I was considering building the app as a locally stored website that took advantage of IndexedDB client side databases/stores. However on further research it doesn't look very useful for this type of task? Seems that all the data is stored in the browser and is not intended to be written out.

Is it posible to share IndexedDB with other users without any server side implementation?

Answer (score 1):

No, the whole idea of IndexedDB and other client-side storage solutions is that they’re client side. You generally need server support to sync data between clients. [PouchDB](http://pouchdb.com/) can sync but you won’t be able to connect to another browser as a browser doesn’t normally have the privilege of listening at ports.

Is your idea that users would access the application by opening an HTML file on a network drive? You could check out [TiddlyWiki](http://tiddlywiki.com/), which uses a Firefox addon to allow users to update the wiki. But given your restricted environment, maybe even that isn’t possible.